# What Continuous Integration tasks/plugins should I install as a minimum?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I'm currently setting up a CruiseControl.Net CI service to keep on top of a bunch of .NET WinForm, WPF and ASP.NET applications maintained by a handful of programmers. I've got basic SVN integration and NUnit running, and I like the thought of running some sort of code quality/duplication of effort checking too.

So my question is what CI tasks do people run that I shouldn't really live without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions that come free, are not too difficult to integrate and offer the most bang the bucks:

- integrate StyleCop into your (I presume) C# VisualStudio projects (see my answer to [Best way to integrate StyleCop with TFS CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557773/best-way-to-integrate-stylecop-with-tfs-ci))
- add FxCop as a first step after the compilation (see here http://igorbrejc.net/development/continuous-integration/fxcop-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Igor Brejc mentioned, I would add similarity analysis.  [Simian](http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/) is the tool you'd be able to use with CruiseControl.  As an aside, this capability is built-in to [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/code_quality.html).  Visual Studio 2012 Premium also has this capability (you'll find it under Analyze->Analyze Solution for Code Clones).