# Check Naming Style Conventions in a TFS Build

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, tfsbuild

We are currently introducing a zero compiler warning guideline for our checkins.

But there are other things to check. For general static code analysis rules we can use `FxCop` and co (unused variables etc).

But what about naming conventions (variables, constants, class names etc)? For example we're having some special naming convention (e.g. we use the m_ prefix when declaring a private member).

Are there ways / tools to check these naming conventions we have, similar the way `ReSharper` does it?

I would like to integrate those convention checks into our gated checkins and usual build definitions, but haven't found any way to do it yet.

Comment: StyleCop is just a tool. However questions about tools and tutorials are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Which site do you want me to put it at?

Comment: An alternative approach, if you're running VS2017, is [Code Style Configurations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/12/15/code-style-configuration-in-the-vs2017-rc-update/) and mark your specific style as an Error. It's not exactly what you're asking for. But it can serve as an alternative.

Comment: I'm not sure questions _about_ StyleCop are off topic, what's off topic is _asking_ for a tool. Have a look at [Best way to integrate StyleCop with TFS CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557773/best-way-to-integrate-stylecop-with-tfs-ci)

Answer (score 1):

To integrate with TFS, you could create a **code analysis check-in policy** for your project.

> Check-in policies are specified and enforced for a team project, but
>   code analysis runs are configured and run for individual code projects
>   **on local development computers.**

This **[tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/creating-and-using-code-analysis-check-in-policies)** describes how to specify code analysis check-in policies for a team project and how to implement custom code analysis policies for managed code.

How to add words and tokens to the dictionary that is referenced in code analysis naming rules, please refer: [Customize the Code Analysis Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-customize-the-code-analysis-dictionary)

Another way is using some 3-party tool just like comment suggested and use the tool integrate with TFS.